# How can I develop my own toolbox

Tags: visual-studio

I want to develop a toolbox from scratch just like in Visual Studio. What should I be studying for or focusing on?

It would be helpful if I could get a head start by seeing an example from the ground up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, be aware that you are starting something that has a high learning curve at your level, and will take months to get what you want without guidance.

This is how I started and have been at it for awhile. I am on my third complete rewrite of my toolbox.

With respect to .NET System.Windows.Forms start with IToolboxService and ToolboxService, which will lead you into component oriented architecture and DesignMode with designers. A toolbox just holds the type for a component and it's subclasses, and needs a designer to construct the tool.

There are more incomplete and bad code examples on the Internet that will lead you down the wrong path so take everything not from Microsoft with scepticism.

One of the better examples of a toolbox with source code can be found in Sharp Develop.